# karma coverage shows 0/0, 100% coverage

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, karma-coverage

My coverage numbers are always showing up as 0/0 and 100%.  i found a few links pointing to bug reports and documentation but none helped.

here is my config file

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '../../..',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        "./CloudConnect.PE.TheApp/Static/CloudConnect.Web.Shared/js/common.js",
        "./CloudConnect.PE.Test/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js",
        "./CloudConnect.PE.TheApp/Static/CloudConnect.Web.Shared/js/bridge/browser.min.js",
        { pattern: "./CloudConnect.PE.TheApp/Static/CloudConnect.Web.Shared/js/bridge/**/*.js", watched: false, included: false },
        { pattern: "./CloudConnect.PE.TheApp/Static/CloudConnect.Web.Shared/css/**/*.css", watched: false, included: true, served: true },
        { pattern: "./CloudConnect.PE.TheApp/Static/CloudConnect.Web.Shared/images/*.*", watched: false, included: false, served: true },
        "./CloudConnect.PE/static/cloudconnect.pe/js/shared.js",
        "./CloudConnect.PE.Test/Client/ActWeb/tests/init.spec.js", // always load init.spec.js
        "./CloudConnect.PE.ActWeb/static/CloudConnect.PE.ActWeb/js/app.js",
        "./CloudConnect.PE.Test/Client/ActWeb/tests/**/*.spec.js"
    ],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
        "./CloudConnect.PE.ActWeb/static/cloudconnect.pe.actweb/js/app.js": ["coverage"]
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

    coverageReporter: {
        type: 'html',
        dir: './CloudConnect.PE.Test/Client/coverage/ActWeb'
    }
    });
```

};

I had to remove some of the config so SO would let me post. Apparently i had to much code in my post with the full config.

Answer (score 1):

Although the paths are not case sensitive by themselves, the files path and the preprocessors path need to match exactly.

I got it working by changing this:

```
preprocessors: {
        "./CloudConnect.PE.ActWeb/static/cloudconnect.pe.actweb/js/app.js": ["coverage"]
    }
```

to this

```
preprocessors: {
        "./CloudConnect.PE.ActWeb/static/CloudConnect.PE.ActWeb/js/app.js": ["coverage"]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All the instructions are missing the bit about setting up webpack with istanbul-instrumenter-loader.

```
{
    test: /\.ts/,
    include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
    loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
    enforce: 'post'
}
```